# Error while installing crontab

Tags: centos, cron

I am getting this error when trying to install the below package. Could some one help me?

```
$ rpm -i crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch.rpm

warning: crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY

error: Failed dependencies:

     /etc/cron.d is needed by crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do it using Sudo
2. use Yum:

> ```
>  yum install crontabs
> ```

1. resolve the dependencies yourself by installing PackageKit-cron-0.5.8-21.el6.x86_64.rpm from Centos site http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: Certain sites are blocked and i couldn't run yum install' so i downloaded the package and trying to run the rpm command.

Comment: then just install the dependencies yourself 
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/
I think you need  PackageKit-cron-0.5.8-21.el6.x86_64.rpm

Comment: I have installed this package
rpm -Uvh  vixie-cron-3.0.1-39.src.rpm

Comment: Should also do the trick :). Basically you've needed to resolve the dependencies (which yum does for you)